# Magento2: "Use Default Value" for description. How to uncheck

Tags: magento2, product

"Use Default Value" in standard is selected for all  stores view.

In products --> Catalog I can switch store view example from default store view to English and then edit product and then in description uncheck "Use Default Value".

In single product I can switch store view: 
[image]

and then uncheck:
[image]

But for above 11k products take more time. Any one know how to uncheck for all products description in one time?

@UPDATE

I will checked in database `catalog_product_entity` and then try edit sample product.

After this I see only value:
[image]

@update2:
[image]

Comment: do you want to keep the default value as it is for another store?

Comment: I want to uncheck "Use default value" on short description for all store view

Comment: in that case you can select all rows where attribute_id=<attribute_id of short_description> and store_id=0 in catalog_product_entity_text table and re insert all those row in same table with store_id=<another store id>. because magento will checked  `Use default value` checkbox if there is no store wise entry for specific attribute. if magento will get any value for specific store of specific attribute then `Use default value` checkbox will be unchecked. Take db or table backup before action this and also try only for one product first.

Comment: Satish, can you please check my update? I edit sample product in table catalog_product_entity_text and I see this field you write. But what next?

Comment: You dont need to update the row, you have to insert the row with same value  again with different store id, and the you can check that product in that store for which you inserted row. https://prnt.sc/mhby7k  https://prnt.sc/mhbzhp

Comment: If you want to empty short_descrption of all product for specific store, you can choose mass action > update attributes .

Comment: Yes, I know how to empty short description in this way, but I want only uncheck "use default value"  for store de, cz, pl etc because I want import miltilanguage description products for this stores. I understand what do you meant but last thing. Can you please describe me more what do you mean "insert row"? How I can do this? Its database so I would not like to do something that I'm not 100% sure

Comment: I know you're right and you're good at me, but I need you to explain to me more. Could you record a short video how you do it? You can do it in response and I know it will work. Then I will be able to mark your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89326/discussion-between-satish-dubariya-and-sylvester).

Comment: Satis, I checked you solution but is correct for single products. How to do for mass all products ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a DB-query for this.

Delete the values in `catalog_product_entity_XXX` for the given attribute and store-id.

XXX stands for the data-type of your attribute.

Comment: Can you please check my update?

Comment: I did and I don't understand hat the problem is. there is no actual checkbox. it just the entries in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Check you store id , go to mysql database search for stock with your number , and write sql query that update table ( just delete value 1 )
It will be very fast way.